# Tabulator context menu won't show

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabulator

I have a problem with Tabulator.js library. I am usig version 4.8, I would like to use context menu feature, but I am unable to make it work. When I use code from documentation (see bellow) browser default context menu is replaced by nothing (nothing shows up). I was not able to find answer to this. Is here someone with similar experience? I have tried three different browsers,but behavior appears to be same in every one of them.

```
rowContextMenu: [
    {
        label:"Hide Column",
        action:function(e, column){
            column.hide();
        }
    },
    {
        separator:true,
    },
    {
        disabled:true,
        label:"Move Column",
        action:function(e, column){
            column.move("col");
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: can you post a link to a JS Fiddle that shows your code in action so we can understand a bit more about how your table is setup?

Comment: Is your table in a modal/dialog/popup of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the example is in error.  The rowContextMenu action function does not provide a Column component.  It provides a Row component.

If you want to manipulate a column you will need to setup Column Menus. Start by looking here and scroll down to see the other options - http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/menu#header-menu.

For Rows look at Row Context Menus - http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/menu#row-context

Answer (score 0):

Unfourtunately, it was all my mistake, I surely did update tabulator js version but forgot to change CSS file, so menu was working right but was shown as div without styling on the bottom.